# C++ implementation of a singly linked list

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I'm trying to implement a singly linked list in C++. Here's my node.

```
template <typename T> struct snode{
    explicit snode(const T& val, snode* ptr=0) : value(val), next(ptr){}
    T value;
    snode* next;
};
```

Here's my slist

```
template <typename T> class slist{
public:
    class iterator;

    slist() : head_(0){}

    //Need to assign copy constructor
    //assignment operator
    //destructor

    bool empty() const{ return (head_ == 0);}
    int size() const;
    iterator begin();
    iterator end();

    void insert(iterator p, const T& t);
    void erase(iterator p);

private:
    snode<T>* head_;
};
```

And here's the iterator

```
class iterator{
public:
    explicit iterator(snode<T>* node = 0) : node_(node){}

    T& operator*(){return node_->value; }
    T* operator->(){return &(node_->value); }

    iterator& operator++(){
        if(node_ != 0)node_ = node_->next;
        return *this;
    }
    iterator operator++(int){
        iterator tmp = *this;
        if(node_ != 0) node_ = node_->next;
        return tmp;
    }
    bool operator==(const iterator& iter) const{return (node_ == iter.node_);}

    bool operator!=(const iterator& iter) const{ return (node_ != iter.node_);}

    snode<T>* node_;
};
```

The issue is since I've declared iterator inside slist, I should have an access to the generic T object in the iterator definition. This isn't happening. I continue to get a squiggly on T saying

```
can't resolve symbol T
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing an explicit instantiated (or casted) type.  "T" Can't compile because it can't resolve what "T" reconciles to.  Iterator class needs to be "templated" or explicitly casted within the class in order to reconcile.

Comment: I'm not sure, I follow. Could you modify the code a bit to help me understand.

Answer (score 0):

Since `iterator` is declared as a nested class of the class template `slist`, you'll need to define `iterator` using the following syntax:

```
template <typename T> class slist<T>::iterator { ... };
```

Comment: @Jumper, there can be many things that prevent your code from working. Here's a skeletal working program that demonstrates the correctness of the syntax. http://ideone.com/5hCk6d